# C#: Is there a way to access the main thread for a little while and go back to secondary thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I am using WinForms and I am stuck. I am invoking a new Thread to do some background data checking. When checking for data, it needs to create a new Control element.

In order other features not to act up, I want the main UI thread to create the element. To do that, I have to switch back to my main thread, create the element there (accessible globally), switch back to the second thread and add necessary features.

My goal is to create a control where the owner of the control is the main UI, but the event fired to create the control is from a secondary thread. How do I do this?

I hope my question is not too confusing

Comment: from memory, you would need to use a backgroundworker, do what you need to do, step out, do what you need to do and step back in again. you cant be half in and half out. Take a look at this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/backgroundworker-in-C-Sharp/ or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: [How to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls)

Comment: @SimonPrice I am confused about the step out and step back in thing you said. The documents only talk about creating a background task and running it till it ends or it is canceled.

Comment: Alexander's link shows the right way. Call BackgroundWorker for the bits you need to invoke on the background thread, and call Control.Invoke for the bits you need to invoke on the UI thread.

Comment: "I am invoking a new Thread to do some background data checking." Show the code. Async/await is always there to help out if you do write your code following the pattern, and no need to use the legacy BackgroundWorker. https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-replace-backgroundworker-with-async-await-and-tasks-80d7c8ed89dc

Comment: @DawitAseged - You can't create, **access**, nor **update** a UI element from a non-UI thread. It doesn't make sense to need a reference to the control on a background thread. Just do all of your background data work and invoke the data onto the UI thread and then make your controls there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for all the comments. Apparently, the easiest way to implement it was using a background worker as @SimonPrice said. It is much easier than creating a new thread inside a function that does the background task

I had to restructure the code, but now it's cleaner and more efficient. Moreover, the cross-thread manipulation error is easily handled now.

Thanks again